# Azure AD B2C and Graph: cannot list users with memberOf

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to list users from my B2C tenant along with groups they belong to. I'm connecting to Graph in app mode like this:

```
var clientCred = new ClientCredential("<client id>",  "<secret>");
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + "<b2c tenant>");
var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", clientCred).Result;
var client = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        async (requestMessage) =>
        {
            var token = authResult.AccessToken;
            var result = await Task.FromResult(token);

            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
        }));

var users = client
    .Users
    .Request()
    .Select("memberOf")  // not working
    //.Select(u => new { u.MemberOf }) // not working
    .Expand("memberOf") // not working
    //.Expand(u => new { u.MemberOf }) // not working
    .GetAsync()
    .Result
    .ToList();
```

As a result I get list of my users with some data but the `MemberOf` field is always null (though i'm 100% sure they have at least one assigned group). Yet, this works as expected:

```
var u = client.Users["<id>"].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Just to be sure, I've granted my app full app permissions, nothing changed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you mean "Yet, this doesn't works as expected:" ?

Comment: I wrote "it works"; not: "doesn't". Long story short: when i ask for a single user I can get his groups. When I try to list all users - I can't.

Answer (score 1):

It's my first answer I hope I can help you.

You should use the beta version since v1.0 does not implement the "memberOf" expand, to change the sdk to the beta version you have to add:

```
 client.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";
```

I usually include the expand using QueryOption as follows:

```
 List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption> { new QueryOption("$Expand", "MemberOf") };
```

But I think that the way you are using it will not have any problems

Try this code:

```
var clientCred = new ClientCredential("<client id>",  "<secret>");
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + "<b2c tenant>");
var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", clientCred).Result;
        var client = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    var token = authResult.AccessToken;
                    var result = await Task.FromResult(token);

                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                }));
        //Change to the beta version
        client.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";
        //Parameters of the query
         List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption> { new QueryOption("$Expand", "MemberOf") };
        // query with parameters
         var users = await graphClient.Users.Request(options).GetAsync();
```

Comment: A good answer should include some explanation of the problem and/or the solution. If nothing else, say what changes you made to the code.

Comment: @Sergio: It got me a step further but not in the desired direction ;) Adding `$Expand` results in `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Service_InternalServerError`. On the other hand: when I remove expand clause users contain a lot of other data that I also couldn't get (like custom user attributes in `AdditionalData`). Also i'm having a mental problem with using something ending with "beta" on my production env ;)

Comment: @Krzysztof in my case this query does not return any errors and if the values memberOf. I know that the beta version is not the best way to get this value but I am afraid that if you do not want to make an added query you should use it. I'm sorry if my answer has not been able to help you.

Comment: @SergioPerales: I should have done more research. I just stumbled upon this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52454887/4556938 and i it basically prooves your point.